# Select items the user does NOT like

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

In my website, I have a users table, primary key is `username`. I have an albums table with an album id and an album title. I have also a table user_albums that models the relationship of many users like many albums.

This is a select query that returns the albums a particular user likes:

```
SELECT e.album_title
FROM user_albums d
INNER JOIN albums e ON d.album_id = e.album_id
WHERE d.user_id = $user
```

What I want is the same query, but I want it to return all the albums he does *not* like. So basically, select all albums not in that query.

What would I need to change to do this?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This translates to a NOT EXISTS, "this user's id is not listed in the user_albums":

```
SELECT e.album_title FROM albums e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 ( SELECT * FROM user_albums d 
    WHERE d.user_id = '$user'
      AND d.album_id = e.album_id
 )
```

If you don't want to use a subquery the common way is to use an OUTER JOIN/IS NULL:

```
SELECT e.album_title 
FROM user_albums d 
LEFT JOIN albums e 
ON d.album_id = e.album_id 
AND d.user_id = '$user' -- when there's no match a NULL will be returned
WHERE d.album_id IS NULL; -- find that NULL
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a subquery.

Comment: @Milo. Such query is usually easier to read with a subquery. EXISTS uses a correlated subquery, i.e. you reference the outer table in that subquery. You can do the same with a non-correlated subquery with IN: `WHERE album_id NOT IN (select album_id from user_albums where user_id = '$user')`, which I consider even more readable.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: Of course NOT IN is easier to read, but NOT EXISTS works regardless of possible NULLs :-)